How to manually deploy a NodeJS application to an azure wep app service (linux) via FTPS
I am trying to manually deploy payloadcms to azure web app services. I have locally run "npm run build" and created the build and dist folders. I then ftps into our server and copy the build and dist folder to wwwroot. From there I run node dist/server.js which results in an error on the server:
root@mosaic-pay_bd31a08ed4:/home/site/wwwroot# node dist/server.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
Require stack:
- /home/site/wwwroot/dist/server.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
    at Module.patchedRequire (/agents/nodejs/node_modules/diagnostic-channel/dist/src/patchRequire.js:16:46)
    at Hook._require.Module.require (/agents/nodejs/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:167:34)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/site/wwwroot/dist/server.js:42:32)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/home/site/wwwroot/dist/server.js' ]
}

From my understanding this was all that was needed to run payload for a manual deployment. Is there something I am missing?

Make sure that the dotenv package is listed under the dependencies in your package.json file. Because it fails load dotenv package.

what is the configuration on your azure machine?, if you have something like this
enter image description here
you need change to something like this
enter image description here
put atention on the field Startup Command
you must put "node dist/server.js" on here field
Update
Sorry, my mistake was that it read 'dotnet' but it said 'dotenv', did you add the package 'dotenv' in dependencies or debDependencies in package.json?

I will put that in the startup command as a try but yes I am using node 20LTS as my stack and not .NET.

Unfortunately that did not fix the issue.
